# C# UWP MediaPlayerElement customize TransportControls CCSelection with Choose Subtitle

Tags: c#, uwp, controls, transport, mediaplayerelement

In C# UWP i overrided the MediaPlayerElement's trasnportcontrol. I didn't find anything about how can i extend my code to add a button inside the CCSelectionButton's MenuFlyoutItem in order to be able to add subtitles to the video after it has been loaded. Just like in the Media player:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNvko.png)

I used this documentation to add subtitle to the current videos, but i didn't find anything about my problem mentioned above: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/VideoPlayback/cs/Scenario4_DisplayingOutOfBandClosedCaptions.xaml.cs

Comment: It seems that adding buttons in the CCSelectionButton's MenuFlyoutItem is not possible. Is it acceptable to add buttons externally like the official sample [Create custom transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/custom-transport-controls)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found  that these menuitems in a MenuFlyoutPresenter, and if i override it in the app.xaml, it is possible to add a button inside the MenuFlyoutPresenter's template. But the button has to be a click event, which should not be in the app.xaml.cs... But if i move the code to the xaml where the mediaplayerelement has been implemented, it is not working. (Maybe because it does not have an x:Key which would be used in the CCSelection button's flyout.) I could not find any information about what is the structure of the CCSelection button's menu flyout...

Comment: Yes, there is no information about the CCSelection. Is it acceptable to add buttons externally like the official sample Create custom transport controls? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/custom-transport-controls